recuperar un campo de la base de datos en un formulario de edición
espero que me podais ayudar en con esta incidencia. Me estoy volviendo loca buscando la solución y quizás he hecho tantas cosas que ya no veo lo que debe de estar mal.
Se trata de un formulario de edición. A este formulario se están pasando los datos correctos de la base de datos del usuario que se va a editar, excepto el campo "company" que muestra el del usuario logado lo cual no es correcto. He hecho varias comprobaciones, para ver si los datos recuperados del usuario coinciden con el usuario a editar. Los datos impresos por var_dump siempre muestran los datos correctos, pero en el formulario me pasa la company del logado. Necesito la del que se va a editar. Os dejo el código completo con php, las consultas de sql para recuperar los datos y el html del formulario.
   <?php
session_start();
include('includes/db.php');

// Verificar si el usuario está autenticado
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] !== true) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}

// Verificar si el usuario actual es gerente
if ($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] !== 'gerencia') {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}

// Obtener el ID del usuario a editar de forma segura
$user_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : null;

// Verificar si se proporcionó un ID válido
if (!$user_id) {
    echo "ID de usuario no válido.";
    exit;
}

// Obtener los datos del usuario a editar
$query = "SELECT id, nombre, email, id_tipo_usuario, id_supervisor, company FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $user_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $nombre, $email, $id_tipo_usuario, $id_supervisor, $company);

// Intentar obtener una fila
if (!mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    echo "No se encontró ningún usuario con el ID proporcionado.";
    exit;
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

// Verificar si se ha enviado el formulario de edición
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Recuperar y validar los datos del formulario
    $nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $tipo_usuario = !empty($_POST['tipo_usuario']) ? $_POST['tipo_usuario'] : null;
    $supervisor = !empty($_POST['supervisor']) ? $_POST['supervisor'] : null;
    $company = !empty($_POST['company']) ? $_POST['company'] : $company;

    // Depuración adicional
    error_log("POST - Nombre: $nombre, Email: $email, Tipo de Usuario: $tipo_usuario, Supervisor: $supervisor, Company: $company");

    $query = "UPDATE usuarios SET nombre = ?, email = ?, id_tipo_usuario = ?, id_supervisor = ?, company = ? WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssissi", $nombre, $email, $tipo_usuario, $supervisor, $company, $user_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) > 0) {
        header('Location: dashboard_gerente.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Error al actualizar el usuario.";
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

// Obtener todos los tipos de usuario
$query_tipos_usuario = "SELECT * FROM tipo_usuario";
$result_tipos_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $query_tipos_usuario);

if (!$result_tipos_usuario) {
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta de tipos de usuario: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
}

$tipos_usuario = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_tipos_usuario)) {
    $tipos_usuario[] = $row;
}

// Obtener los supervisores
$query_supervisores = "SELECT id, nombre FROM supervisor";
$result_supervisores = mysqli_query($conn, $query_supervisores);

if (!$result_supervisores) {
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta de supervisores: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
}

$supervisores_data = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_supervisores)) {
    $supervisores_data[] = $row;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Editar Usuario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Encabezado -->
        <?php include('layouts/header.php'); ?><br>
        
        <!-- Formulario de edición de usuario -->
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Editar Usuario</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="edit_user.php?id=<?php echo $user_id; ?>" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($nombre); ?>" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="tipo_usuario">Tipo de Usuario:</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="tipo_usuario" required>
                                    <?php foreach ($tipos_usuario as $tipo) : ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $tipo['id']; ?>" <?php echo ($tipo['id'] == $id_tipo_usuario) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                                            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($tipo['tipo']); ?>
                                        </option>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="supervisor">Supervisor:</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="supervisor">
                                    <option value="">Seleccionar Supervisor</option>
                                    <?php foreach ($supervisores_data as $supervisor) : ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $supervisor['id']; ?>" <?php echo ($supervisor['id'] == $id_supervisor) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                                            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($supervisor['nombre']); ?>
                                        </option>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="company">Empresa:</label>
                                <select name="company" class="form-control" readonly>
                                    <?php
                                    $allowed_values = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
                                    foreach ($allowed_values as $value) {
                                        $selected = (strcasecmp($value, $company) === 0) ? 'selected' : '';
                                        echo "<option value=\"$value\" $selected>$value</option>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>
                            <a href="dashboard_gerente.php" class="btn btn-danger">Volver</a>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><br><br>
        
        <!-- Pie de página -->
        <?php include('layouts/footer.php'); ?>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Gracias de antemano

¿Has mirado el código generado con el inspector de tu navegador?  Sobretodo mírate el select de company para darte cuenta de si se está poniendo correctamente el selected o no, pues tiene toda la pinta que el problema lo tienes allí.

@masterguru lo he comprobado y no me da errores

No digo que de errores, sino que mires si te aparece el selected en alguno de ellos, en ninguno o bien en todos, pues esa comparación que tienes podria ser la causante del problema.  Si no te sale ningun selected o bien te sale en todos los <option> entonces mira de cambiar los tres = por dos = en la comparación a ver si con eso se arregla.

¿Qué tienes definido en tu variable $company? Con estos datos de prueba el código funciona del modo esperado:
<?php
    $user_id=1;
    $nombre="Test";
    $email="test@email.com";
    $id_tipo_usuario=1;
    $id_supervisor=2;
    $company='B'; # ¿Qué tienes aquí en tu contexto?
    $tipos_usuario=[
        ['id'=>1,'tipo'=>'A', 'nombre'=>'Usuario1'],
        ['id'=>2,'tipo'=>'B', 'nombre'=>'Usuario2']
    ];
    $supervisores_data=[
        ['id'=>1,'tipo'=>'A', 'nombre'=>'Supervisor1'],
        ['id'=>2,'tipo'=>'B', 'nombre'=>'Supervisor2']
    ];
?>

La salida la puedes ver en el snippet. En company aparece seleccionada B, que es la que cumple la condición evaluada en esta parte de tu código:
$allowed_values = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
foreach ($allowed_values as $value) {
    $selected = (strcasecmp($value, $company) === 0) ? 'selected' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"$value\" $selected>$value</option>";
}

No veo entonces cuál es el problema...
¿O, entendí yo algo mal en el planteamiento de la pregunta? Si es el caso, ¿cuál es la salida esperada, en base a esos datos de prueba?


<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Encabezado -->

  <!-- Formulario de edición de usuario -->
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Editar Usuario</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form action="edit_user.php?id=1" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" value="Test" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="test@email.com" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tipo_usuario">Tipo de Usuario:</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="tipo_usuario" required>
                <option value="1" selected>
                  A </option>
                <option value="2">
                  B </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="supervisor">Supervisor:</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="supervisor">
                <option value="">Seleccionar Supervisor</option>
                <option value="1">
                  Supervisor1 </option>
                <option value="2" selected>
                  Supervisor2 </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="company">Empresa:</label>
              <select name="company" class="form-control" readonly>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B" selected>B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
                <option value="D">D</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>
            <a href="dashboard_gerente.php" class="btn btn-danger">Volver</a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><br><br>
</div>




Hola Cedano. En consola me imprime los datos correctos, pero es en el formulario donde no aparece bien y es lo que no entiendo, algo hace que en formulario salga dato incorrecto. Cada usuario que abro para editar me muestra en el campo company siempre el mismo valor y eso no es correcto, sin embargo en consola, sí sale correcto y en la base de datos.

@Monica posiblemente estás modificando otro archivo o bien el archivo antiguo se ha quedado almacenado en caché.

@Cedano he borrado caché. La comprobación que he hecho es que me muestre la company del usuario a editar en la consola y en el formulario, en la consola es la que pasa de la base de datos y la que debería salir y es correcta, pero en el formulario la company que me muestra e imprime es la del usuario logado, no la del usuario a editar. No entiendo realmente por qué sale la company del usuario logado en todos los usuarios de la tabla que abra para editar cuando ne la tabla sale correctamente la company que hay guardada en la base de datos de cada usuario

@Monica depura y revisa tus archivos, revisa tu entorno, etc. El problema no está en este código, como demuestra mi respuesta, sino en algún archivo viejo cacheado, o en la lógica, o en alguna otra parte de tu programa. Sin tener todo el contexto es imposible para nosotros poder ayudar. Cuando no hallas salida lo mejor es dividir el código en procesos pequeños e ir probando pieza por pieza hasta ver dónde está el problema. Nunca está de más revisar el log de errores, el cual, si lo tienes activado (si no lo tienes deberías hacerlo) te podría informar de otros problemas que no están a la vista.
